# result set returning only one row on executing the query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, resultset

I was trying to retrieve the datas from the DB via a java function. There are more than 1 rows in my DB but the result set is returning the first row of the table only.

```
public class checkoutDAOj {
    static Connection con=DBConnection.getConnection();
    static PreparedStatement ps=null;
    static ResultSet rs=null;
    static String stmnt;

    public static ArrayList<products> selectcart(String uname)
    {
        ArrayList<products> ap=ap=new ArrayList<>();
        products p=null;

        ps=null;
        rs=null;

        stmnt="select PID,P_QTY,P_SIZE from cart where uname=?";
        try {
            ps=con.prepareStatement(stmnt);
            ps.setString(1, uname);
            rs=ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs!=null)
            {
                int cou=0;
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    p=new products();
                    p.setPid(rs.getInt(1));
                    p.setP_quantity(rs.getInt(2));
                    p.setP_size(rs.getInt(3));
                    p=selectproduct(p);
                    ap.add(p);
                    p=null;
                    System.out.println(cou++);
                }
                System.out.println(ap);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return ap;
    }

    private static products selectproduct(products p)
    {

        ps=null;
        rs=null;
        stmnt="select p_name,p_image,p_price from Products where pid=?";
        try
        {
            ps=con.prepareStatement(stmnt);
            ps.setInt(1,p.getPid());
             rs=ps.executeQuery();
            if(rs!=null)
            {
                while(rs.next())
                {
                p.setName(rs.getString(1));
                p.setP_image(rs.getBlob(2));
                p.setP_price(rs.getDouble(3));
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return p;
    }

}
```

I was using two functions in this code and to retrieve a complete information about the product.

I was using **Oracle**  as DB in **sqldeveloper**

Comment: Do you have multiple rows having the same value for uname column?

Comment: yeah its my foreign key, I have multiple rows with same uname value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `prepareStatement` in `selectproduct` the cursor is closed on the connection in `selectcart`. You need `n` `Statements`s where `n` is the number of queries you're going to run (here you need `2`). Also, you can't explicitly `null` the shared `ResultSet` and `PreparedStatement`(s). In fact, you can't share those either.

```
private static products selectproduct(products p)
{
    ps=null; // <-- ends the query in the other method.
    rs=null; // <-- ends the query in the other method.
```

Comment: I have just edited the code i pasted my full java code here i have used the connection as global variable even though i need `N` connections??

Comment: even if i remove the `ps=null;` and `rs=null;` in the code the result is same and there is no change @Elliot_Frisch

Comment: @nsuriya239 You cannot share those variables. Method one gets a row, method two takes the **single** statement and resultset away. That is why you only get one row.

Comment: Its Working Thank you @Elliot_Frisch

Comment: Be aware that auto-commit being enabled can have similar effects.